# Bootstrap Classes are undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using Bootstrap 5.3.0 and have imported it via CDN links into my JS script.  Here is how I am injecting via my js file which is being placed into the existing website's DOM via a chrome extension called Scripty, which is just a JS injector extension for chrome:

```
function loadFile(path, type) {
    if (type == "js") {
      var fileref = document.createElement("script");
      fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
      fileref.setAttribute("src", path);
    } else if (type == "css") {
      var fileref = document.createElement("link");
      fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
      fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
      fileref.setAttribute("href", path);
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
  }
```

Then calling:

```
loadFile("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css","css");
loadFile("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js","js");
```

I can see the files are correctly loaded and referenced in the header from the browser dev tools:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

However, later in my js script when I try to create a an object I get an error that the bootstrap class does not exist.  Here is my code to initialize the new instance of the class:

```
  const bsContactMenu = new bootstrap.Offcanvas('#contactMenu');
```

Here is the error from the dev tools in the browser:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined
    at AllInOne (<anonymous>:188:26)
    at <anonymous>:631:17
```

However if you look at this exact class in the developer Tools->Watch, it is defined so I know the bootstrap class definitions were imported correctly from CDN link.  Why then am I getting an error showing it as undefined?

Watch from Developer Tools

[image: Watch from Developer Tools]

I expect that the bootstrap.Offcanvas class should be resolved in the browser since the developer tools show that it is defined in the DOM.

Comment: The error says that `bootstrap` is undefined.

Comment: Did you load `bootstrap.js` asynchronously?

Comment: You'll need to show us how you load bootstrap and your script into the page. What does it mean that "*bootstrap class definitions were imported correctly from CDN link*"? Please [edit] your question to include that code.

Comment: Did you watch the expression before or after the error occurred? This might be a timing issue.

Comment: Make sure your script tag is after the one that loads bootstrap.

Comment: I added the code showing how the CDN content is loaded correctly, I am not using HTML but doing the injection via JS as a document Element to load the CDN URLs, see the code snip above.  Also, the question is being posted because bootstrap is undefined, which according to the browser dev tools via the watch and element inspector, the bootstrap file was loaded correctly in the header and is defined in the watch.

Comment: [I've just tested the dynamic load, it seems to work fine](https://jsbin.com/nukuzixulu/edit?html,js,output). Can you provide more context on the process leading to the creation of the Offcanvas ?

Comment: So after I load the CDN sources as shown above, and as you tested, I have a function call AllInOne where I then just simply try to create a new object from the class Offcanvas.  like so:

function AllInOne() {
  const bsContactMenu = new bootstrap.Offcanvas('#contactMenu');
}

Then call this function like so at the bottom of the JS script:

document.onload(AllInOne());

This must be an issue with the JS injector extension ?

Comment: So after building the OffCanvas HTML code in JS the error with respect to bootstrap went away.  The problem seems to be in the constructor for bootstrap.Offcanvas.  The ID I was sending didnt exist in the DOM, so a correct constructor was not being found.  Once I added the correct HTML code of the Offcanvas element, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

You could try do it after DOM is loaded

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
    {
      const bsContactMenu = new bootstrap.Offcanvas('#contactMenu');
    });
```

Or just check up they inluding order

Comment: Script loading doesn't usually depend on the DOM being loaded.

Comment: I tried this and while the error goes away, the content in the block doesnt execute or work, so I dont think this works.